# HTTP is not subscriptable issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to integrate the 2capcha text solver in one of my applications but i am coming accross the error: ***'HTTPResponse' object is not subscriptable***

code:

```
import time
from urllib import request, parse

class CaptchaTextSolver(object):

def solve_text(self, captcha_api_key, phrase_to_solve):   
    try:                   
        postUrl = "https://2captcha.com/in.php"
        result = ""
        values = {'key': captcha_api_key, 'method': 'POST', 'textcaptcha': phrase_to_solve}
        data = parse.urlencode(values).encode()

        req = request.Request(postUrl, data=data)
        res = request.urlopen(req)
        print(res)
        if res[0:3] == 'OK|':
            captchaID = res[3:]
            print("--> " + captchaID)

            for i in range(0, 24):
                req = request.Request("https://2captcha.com/res.php?key=" + captcha_api_key + "&action=get&id=" + captchaID)
                answerResp = request.urlopen(req)
                answerResponse = answerResp.read()

                if len(answerResponse) < 3:
                    result = answerResponse
                    break
                elif answerResponse[0:3] == "OK|":
                    result = answerResponse[3:]
                    break
                elif answerResponse != "CAPCHA_NOT_READY":
                    pass
                time.sleep(5)

        return result        
    except Exception as e: 
        print("2CAPTCHA.COM ERROR: " , e)
```

My code is fairly simple enough, after gooogling the error for a bit i'm still no where near to knowing the issue, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line

```
if res[0:3] == 'OK|':
```

Throws an error because you are trying to grab elements 0,1,2 of res, which is an HTTPResponse object. An HTTPResponse is not subscriptable like a list is. You probably meant to do this

```
response = res.read()
if response[0:3] == 'OK|':
```